# How to use a void() function to print a vector in c++?

Tags: c++, function, vector, printing

I have a function which calculates the squares of the numbers from 1 - 100. I would like to use another function to print the results. I would like to know how to make a function like that not only works with vectors but with any type.

Here's what i have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<double> Sqrs(int val, double sqr, vector<double> result){

for(val = 1;val < 100;val++){
    sqr = sqrt(val);
    result.push_back(sqr);
}
return result;
}
void Print(int val, vector<double> result){
    for(unsigned int i = 0;i < result.size();i++){
        cout << val << setw(10);
        cout << &result << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Print();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it says I have too few arguments on `Print();`. I dont know what arguments to put because when I put the `val`, `result`, or with `int val, vector<double>result`, it gives me a lot of errors. I just don't know how to make a separate function to print something I have used in another function other than `main`.

EDIT: It seems that i have asked the question stupidly. I would like to know for example i have a function that calculates 2 numbers named `int val (int a, int b)` and that function returns a value "c". So now i would like to make another function named `Print` and use the returned value from the other function `val` so i can print it. Then in the main function i would just call the `Print()` function.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the code you have written?

Comment: @indiv the problem is that it says i have too few arguments on Print(); I dont know what arguments to put because when i put the val, result, or with int val, vector<double>result it gives me a lot of errors. I just dont know how to make a separate function to print something i have used in another function other than main

Comment: @nos:  I doubt that's really the question, because the code posted does not work.  (prints `&result` instead of `result[i]`)

Comment: @LiGNUx Your code is invalid and will not compile. Function Print is declared with two parameters but called without any arguments. It is unclear what the function should output.

Comment: To me, the confusing part is where you take the address of `result`, i.e. `cout << &result`. Why?

Comment: @LiGNUx You've been missing to have an instance of `vector<double>` passed as parameter to `Print();`, also it's unclear what `val` should mean in this context at all. I'd recommend you study some basics again.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes i know its invalid the thing is i would like to learn how to make this kind of functions in the future. How do i make it clear to the function what to print? Maybe you can fix the code a bit so it can work and i can learn from it.

Comment: @LiGNUx From what I understood, you want to make it a *template function*. Is that it?

Comment: @zenith i have edited my question and hopefully someone can help me now :) .

Comment: You wrote a function to print a vector, but you do not _have_ a vector, so you're not passing a vector to print into your function that prints a vector... and you're wondering what the problem is?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes :). I edited my question so you know what i am asking. The arguments where i asked for the adress of a vector and all that was just edits i made to my code when i tried to make it work.

Comment: There are just too many misconceptions in this code. Please ask a mentor or teacher to walk you through it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The thing is i dont care about this particular code. I just used it to try and explain what i ask. The real question is how to use a separate function to print something thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<double> myFunc(int x, vector<double> &vec){
        double rez = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++){
                rez = sqrt(x);
                vec.push_back(rez);
                x++;
        }
        return vec;
}
void Print(vector<double> &vec){
        for(int i = 0;i != vec.size();i++){
                cout << vec[i] << endl;
        }
}
int main()
{
        vector<double> vec1;
        myFunc(1, vec1);
        Print(vec1);
        return 0;
}
```

This is what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

A brief translation to English of your program at the highest level is:

- Here are the libraries I want to use.
- This is what I mean if I ever ask you to do `Sqrs` with an `int`, a `double`, and a `vector<double>`
- This is what I mean if I ever ask you to do `Print` with an `int` and a `vector<double>`

and finally the thing you actually tell the program to do is

- `Print` with nothing
- Output `0`

So as you can see, this code doesn't really seem to resemble any of the things you describe. Before you worry about trying to write very general code, you should work on trying to get a special case right first.